# Plot result of a loop in same figure - heatmap

Tags: python

i created a dataframe with random columns and values. now i am trying to interate with an loop over "time" window" (maybe there is a more elegant solution than mine). i try to plot the calculated correlations in a heatmap and then interate furhter and show the next result in the same figure. Like this 
https://datasoaring.blogspot.com/2018/07/gdp-correlation-matrix-top-10-economies.html

The current code plot a new figure for each correlation...

Thanks for ideas and help!

> Creates Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style('white')


plt.style.use('dark_background')

index = pd.date_range('01/01/2010',periods=num_days, freq='D')
data_KW = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,250,size=(250, 10)), columns=list('ABCDEFGHIJ'), index=index)

data_KW.head()
```

> interate and plot (wrong :))

```
# Calculate the lenght of the Dataframe
end = 10 #len(data_KW.index)

# is the variable for the rolling window
var_start = 0
var_end = 5

#Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))


while var_end <= end:
    window = data_KW.iloc[var_start : var_end]

    # Compute the correlation matrix
    corr = window.corr()

    # Generate a mask for the upper triangle
    mask = np.zeros_like(corr, dtype=np.bool)
    mask[np.triu_indices_from(mask)] = True


    # Generate a custom diverging colormap
    cmap = sns.diverging_palette(220, 10, as_cmap=True)

    # Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
    sns.heatmap(corr, mask=mask, cmap=cmap, vmax=1, center=0,
                square=True, linewidths=.5, cbar_kws={"shrink": .5})

    #plt.pause(3)
    plt.show()
    time.sleep(2)

    #time.sleep(5)
    var_start = var_start + 1
    var_end = var_end + 1

    print(var_start)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to plot in the same (first and only) heatmap... like in the link. greets alex